# Returning rows with distinct column value with data jpa named query

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2

Assuming I have a table with 3 columns, ID, Name, City and I want to use named query to return rows with unique city..can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking whether it is possible to write a query that will return the cities that appear in exactly one row, in a table that has ID/Name/City triplets where there could be multiple rows for the same city but with different names?
If so, it would depend on the database engine behind the scenes - but you could try things like:

```
with candidates (city, num) as (
    select city, count(*) from table 
    group by city
)
select city from candidates where num = 1
```

Or

```
select t1.city from table t1
where not exists (
    select * from table t2 
    where t2.city = t1.city and t2.id <> t1.id
)
```

where `table` is your table with these triplets.